# Select parts of a UIWebView

Tags: ios, select, uiwebview

I want to open my website in a UIWebView but I need not to shown the upper and lower part of it. So I want for example to select the following part: top + 50 pixels --> bottom - 50 pixels

Is it possible to do in iOS?

Comment: You may do a mobile version for your website, to hide the header and the footer.

Comment: Or requesting the URL, parse & modify HTML, then call `-loadHTMLString:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a demo:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
        NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                        @"var html = document.body.innerHTML;"
                        @"var newHtml = \"<div style='overflow:hidden;'><div style='margin-top:-50px; margin-bottom:-50px; display:block;'>\" + html + \"</div></div>\";"
                        @"document.body.innerHTML = newHtml;"
                        ];
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this is what I was exactly looking for. However, when you click on a link inside the page, the webView opens it with the old scaling. 
And it always keeps on showing an internet connection error. Do you know why?

Comment: @firewall I tested and I've not seen the "old scaling", nor any errors. What's your URL?